# Combining immutable and normal constructor in D?

Tags: d, immutability

Is it possible to write one constructor instead of two and still be able to create both normal and immutable objects? It is a lot of repetitive work to write both normal and immutable constructor.

```
class ExampleClass
{
    void print() const
    {
        writeln(i);
    }

    this(int n)
    {
        i = n * 5;
    }

    this(int n) immutable
    {
        i = n * 5;
    }

private:
    int i;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the constructor `pure` and it can implicitly convert to any qualifiers.

```
this(int n) pure
{
    i = n * 5;
}

auto i = new immutable ExampleClass(2);
auto m = new ExampleClass(3);
```

Documented here:
http://dlang.org/class.html "If the constructor can create unique object (e.g. if it is pure), the object can be implicitly convertible to any qualifiers. "

BTW: the return value of other pure functions implicitly convert too.

```
// returns mutable...
char[] cool() pure {
    return ['c', 'o', 'o', 'l'];
}

void main() {
    char[] c = cool(); // so this obviously works
    string i = cool(); // but since it is pure, this works too
}
```

Same principle at work there, it is unique so it can be assumed to be shared or immutable too.

Comment: You're right that this works for the example case. However in my actual usage case I have to call impure functions like glCreateShader so your solution doesn't work. :/

Comment: @Scintillo In that case, are you actually creating an immutable object? Sounds like it'd allow mutation, in which case you could simply forbid creating an immutable instance of it.

Comment: @Cubic Well it's true that it's possible to mutate the object since OpenGL doesn't really allow you to make resource immutable. Immutable would just prevent changing the resource id wrapper points to and be a guideline "please don't modify this object".

Comment: Did the quick idea on chat work: making a const helper that is called from both mutable and immutable ctors?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Well of course you can't write to members in const functions. However it can remove most of the duplicated code if called like this `i = helper(n);`.

Comment: @Scintillo Immutable means you absolutely guarantee that *no-one* (including openGL internally in your case) will ever change anything that can be accessed through that reference. You should probably use const instead.